# Earth Engine: How can I loop over an image with 400+bands to make an image collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

In Google Earth Engine, I have an image with 400+ bands that represent probabilities through time when they are group by 3. The bands look something like this

- prob1_0
- prob2_0
- prob3_0
- prob1_1
- prob2_1
- prob3_1 ...
- prob1_152
- prob2_152
- prob3_152

I want to select the 3 bands starting with 0 to get a separate image that I can add to an image collection. I understand how to do it for 1 image (as coded below) but I want to be able to loop over the list variable to create an image collection with 153 images.

```
var list = ee.List.sequence(0, 152)
var matchKey = '.*' + list.get(0)
var event0 = ee.Image(image400).select(matchKey).clip(studyArea)
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection([event0])
```

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to loop over each entry in the list to select the bands that match the value of `matchKey`. Finally, you can use `ee.ImageCollection.fromImages` to create an image collection from the list of images.

```
var list = ee.List.sequence(0, 152);

var listImages = list.map(function(number){
  var matchKey = '.*' + number;
  var event0 = ee.Image(image400).select(matchKey);
  
  return event0;
});


var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listImages);
```